# Adding new tab in Product Admin page like Features Tab, Attributes Tab etc. in Prestashop Version 1.5.3

Tags: php, module, e-commerce, prestashop

I would like to add a new tab in Product Admin page like Features Tab, Attributes Tab etc. in PS Version 1.5.x with a custom module.
I am adding this tab to the product edit page so that I can add option to upload product video to the admin.

Here is the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

### **Edit**

I found a solution here: http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-create-a-custom-product-tab-in-prestashop.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will need to create a module that hooks to displayAdminProductsExtra.

displayAdminProductsExtra - this is hook for additional product tab,

in your module you have to register this hook in the install function:

```
!$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra')
```

then you have to create function with this hook:

```
    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params) {
     return $this->display(__FILE__, 'tab-body.tpl');
}
```

and that's all..

Comment: You might also want to use `ActionProductUpdate` hook to hook your values handling code.... or maybe `actionProductSave`, which is called in both add & update of product.